# Add a vertical line with ggplot when x-axis is a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code use to work pre-version .9 of ggplot2. Is this not possible anymore?

```
df = data.frame(x = letters[1:26], y=abs(rnorm(26)))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_bar() + geom_vline(xintercept='m')
```

I get the following error:

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
> object 'm' of mode 'function' was not found

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know (don't remember) if your original used to work with old version of ggplot but you can use an another approach like this one :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_bar() + geom_vline(xintercept=which(df$x == 'm'))
```

Hope this help !!!

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly. Small note for anyone who uses this, if you specify the xlim this will not work correctly. For instances, I am actually reversing the order (i.e. largest to smallest). In that case the which would return the position before reversing. Easy to fix though.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is kind of a more broader discussion for people who wants to add vertical line in customized position in categorized x-axis.

I have five groups and five factors in each group. I want to add 4 vertical lines behind the last factor in each group to separate the five groups (at the 'E' position in this case). The method from @dickoa is not working for my case.  when I use :

```
geom_vline(xintercept=which(df$x == 'm'))
```

It only adds vertical line at 'm' of the 3rd group. 
I just find that I can try sth like this:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5))
```

At least this works perfect for my case. You may need to try several times to find the pattern fitting your case.

I always want to know how to add vertical/ horizontal line based on the proportion of x/y axis. e.g., xintercept = 0.5 means add vertical line in the middle of x-axis, and xintercept = 0.25 means first quarter. However I can't find any knowledge about this topic.