# Group seperation Bar plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a bar plot with three slope estimates, including their standard errors. However, one of these estimates are from another model than the other two. Therefore I would like a gap or a line or so in between so that it is clear they are from different models. Can anyone help me with that? 
My code and my data look like this:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Name, y=Slope))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+geom_errorbar(aes(x=data$Name, ymin=(data$Slope-data$SE_Slope), ymax=(data$Slope+data$SE_Slope), width=.25))


Name   Slope   SE_Slope

BP     1.72       0.43

AP     1.74       0.51

DIF    1.70       0.46
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, moreover mind https://barbarplots.github.io/

Comment: I don't know how, therefore I added my data. Those 3 values with their standard errors is all I have.

Comment: `dput()` outputs the lines needed to a reproducible example. If those 6 figures is the only thing to show, a table shoud do the job don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

geom_vline() may be of use to you! It might work funny with the x axis with geom_bar, but this may help:

[Add a vertical line with ggplot when x-axis is a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236882/add-a-vertical-line-with-ggplot-when-x-axis-is-a-factor)

Additionally, you could use annotate() if you really want to point it out.

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html